# Why doesn't Skype want to turn on?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, skype

What's the problem with Skype that doesn't want to turn on? So yes, I have installed Skype and when I run it it shows up as normal but at the point that it is logged in the process suddenly disappears.

What can I do to remedy this problem?

Comment: Is it no longer running ?(check in the task manager ) or does it just disappear from your icon tray ?

Comment: just try it by uninstall and again install it. it works for me.

Comment: Here are translations of David's and Rosomak's comments. David: Have you tried to reinstall skype? Also, please fix the errors, if any. Some words did not translate in Google. Rosomak: So I tried to install switches on only once and then the council can not. (Google translate is awful.)

Answer (score 0):

try this older version, it seemed to fix this for other people that had the problem.

[DL link here at oldapps.com](http://www.oldapps.com/skype.php?old_skype=92?download)

uninstall the newer version first